# Why doesn't my app ask to use the user's current location when it's downloaded from the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store

I just got my first app approved on the App Store (Woohoo!) and it runs slightly differently depending on whether it's installed from my development machine or the App Store.  When I install and run the App in release mode from my development machine, the app opens and asks the user if it can use their current location.  When I install and run it from the App Store, the app opens and does NOT ask the user if it can use their current location, causing my location-based features not to work.  What are some reasons this might happen?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer here...

[iphone Location Services code that works on OS 4.1 in appstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852028/iphone-location-services-code-that-works-on-os-4-1-in-appstore)

Apparently it's a bug in Apple's 4.1 code that caused me to have to pull my app from the store.  Thanks, Apple!

Answer (score 0):

Hummmm

Did you try on an another device that you "test device" ?

Maybe there is still a certificate that think that's a debug app (it can happen), and maybe the device think you said "no" earlier to this kind of features (location).

But you should avoir this problem by handling errors with delegate methods :-) (of the location API)

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks, Vinzius.  I do handle the errors with delegates and log them for the user to send me, but the errors don't provide much info other than "The operation could not be completed."  That's not much to work with :)

Comment: erf ok :-| and did you try another device ?

Comment: I did try it on two other devices.  Some it works fine, others it doesn't and I can't find any patterns with the behavior and the hardware its running on.  It simply appears to be intermittent :(

Comment: well, i found the answer and just posted it.  thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Is `UIRequiredDeviceCapabililities` not set? Doesn't seem like that should break it but who knows....

Comment: No, I don't have that set since I'd like to give the user the option to use the location-based services, but it appears the Location Services isn't asking the user for permission for some reason.

Comment: well, i found the answer and just posted it.  thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is horrible!  This happened to me as well.  I had invested two months work of time and effort into a paid app and the user reviews were horrible because consumers can't distinguish between a bug in Apple's OS code and a bug in your code.  Consumers just assume your software sucks and lost a lot of revenue as a result.