# Issue with CoreLocation and Adhoc Distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, core-location, adhoc

We're developing an application that uses CoreLocation as a primary feature, where need to poll the GPS over an extended period of time.  Everything works fine when we install via build&run in Xcode, but whenever its installed via adhoc using hockey (ipa generated using build&archive->share_application->distribute_for_enterprise), something very odd is going on with CoreLocation.  Here are the problems we're experiencing; (1) the "Allow xxx to access your current location" dialog is never displayed, (2) the location icon on the taskbar is never shown, and (3) the delegate method, locationManager:didUpdateToLocation... is never called.

To make matters even more confusing, this issue is only reproducible on the developer devices.  Beta testers are not experiencing this.  We have tried removing all provisioning profiles from the developer devices and from Xcode, but the issue still remains.  We have also verified that we are building with the lastest provisioning profile.  I was only able to install via adhoc onto my dev phone after I completely wiped it and set it up as a new phone in iTunes.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or something similar?  Any suggestions/recommendations?

Tested using Xcode 3.2.4 64bit and iOS 4.1 (8B117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly related to [iphone Location Services code that works on OS 4.1 in appstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852028/iphone-location-services-code-that-works-on-os-4-1-in-appstore)?

Comment: Thanks!  This was the exact problem we were experiencing